# How to get current date and time and save it into char* array in proper format?

Tags: c, date, datetime, time, arrays

I know how to get current date & time and save it into an array. But I would like to print it in format: `dd.mm.YYY_HH:MM:ss`. How can I change my code to achieve this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

char *datetime()
{
    char *array = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*25);
    time_t result;
    result = time(NULL);
    sprintf(array, "%s", asctime(localtime(&result)));
    array[25] = '\0';
    return array;
}

int main(void)
{
    // prints Sat Aug  3 18:39:07 2013
    printf("%s", datetime());

    // how to print:
    // 03.08.2013_18:39:07
    // ?

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Use [`strftime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strftime.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using strftime - see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Formatting-Calendar-Time.html)

This will look like this -

```
time_t rawtime;

time (&rawtime);
struct tm  *timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
strftime(array, sizeof(array)-1, "%d.%m.%y_%H:%M:%S", timeinfo);
```

Comment: Hmm, did like you wrote, but got strange output. My edited code: http://pastie.org/private/iku0gjzmqpp1kkujpsdkla and my output: http://oi41.tinypic.com/smq98n.jpg. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strftime`  function:
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Formatting-Calendar-Time.html

`strftime` is described in C99 Standard in 7.23.3.5.